# How can I use NSPredicate with a computed property in Swift?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nspredicate, swift-keypath

I am trying to create a @FetchRequest in SwiftUI using an NSPredicate, like so:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: CoreDataRecipe.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isRunning == true")) var runningRecipes: FetchedResults<CoreDataRecipe>
```

Unfortunately, my `isRunning` property is a computed property like so:

```
var isRunning: Bool {
    get {
        activeStep != nil
    }
}
```

The problem is that NSPredicate will crash since it can't find a string for the computed property when resolving the predicate. Is there any way to make this possible? I would love to use this, since it would allow me to create a nice UX.

> Note: I can't test for activeStep as an alternative, because it is a
> computed property as well with more complex logic.

Comment: Could you show how all properties of `CoreDataRecipe` look like?

Comment: You can't do that because the predicate will be transformed into a SQLite request and `isRunning` is not part of the database.